Two questions on two-term Machin-like formulae
It is known that there are exactly four two-term Machin-like formulae that allow for the estimation of $\pi$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\tfrac {\pi }{4}}&=\arctan {\tfrac {1}{2}}+\arctan {\tfrac {1}{3}}\\
{\tfrac {\pi }{4}}&=2\arctan {\tfrac {1}{2}}-\arctan {\tfrac {1}{7}}\\
{\tfrac {\pi }{4}}&=2\arctan {\tfrac {1}{3}}+\arctan {\tfrac {1}{7}}\\
{\tfrac {\pi }{4}}&=4\arctan {\tfrac {1}{5}}-\arctan {\tfrac {1}{239}}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
I have two questions about this:
(a) Were these two-term formulae stumbled upon serendipitously, or is there a systematic way of deriving them, e.g., by trial and error? If so, how does one proceed?
(b) A widely-quoted paper by Størmer is supposed to have established that there are four and only four two-term Machin-like formulae, as stated above. The paper is in French and, even after using Google Translate incrementally, I have not been able to grasp its logic. Can someone here kindly outline the main steps in the proof please.

Even being French, I must confess that the paper is not very clear

@Claude  also, a gap was later fixed by Ljunggren, modern exposition      https://isis2.cc.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/gausspi.pdf

@WillJagy. Thanks for the link ! But it is in English (joke). Cheers.

@Claude  Very clever!  I'm trying to guess why they don't look for $\pi/6$

I think I have it, for the type of formulas they consider the tangent of the result is rational.

@WillJagy. Good question and good remark and (+1) !

How does one (a) identify all rational tangents in the first quadrant; and (b) reduce them to the four that make it for the two-term Machin formulae?
